# How can I have tomcat and apache running at the same time?

Tags: apache2, tomcat

I've taken over a website and I'd like to run PHP and JSP on the site. I already have tomcat installed and running which I'm assuming is using port 80. I'm trying to install apache so that I can run PHP. I've installed apache and when I try the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

I get the following response from the server:

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
```

How can I have tomcat and apache running at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The port `80` have been binded to the tomcat, so when you start `apache`, it can't bind to the port `80` which is the default port of `apache`.

So you should change the `apache` default port in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` file as
`Listen 8081`
Then you can verify that Apache listing:
`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :8081`

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I update this file from the command line?

Comment: You can use `sudo vim /etc/apache2/ports.conf` to edit it.